# Automator app in notification centre

Tags: macos, automator, notifications

I've made an Automator application that runs displays a notification and then runs a shell script. Works fine. However, the notification centre doesn't display the name of the application, but instead shows some garbled code. I'm using Mavericks. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finder, go to ThisAutomatorThing.app

Right click. Show Package Contents.

Go to folder /Contents/, and open Info.plist file with a text editor. Find something like:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>6ARbL3D-C0D4</string>
```

If the string is exactly the gibberish in notification, replace it with you app name.

You **MIGHT** need to 1) reset LaunchServices to delete the old cache and reflect the change:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user
```

**AND/OR**, 2) reset LaunchPad:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db;killall Finder
```

Comment: `CFBundleName` was already set properly, but after using the terminal commands it is now all good and proper. It's also showing the right icon now. Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to upvote your answer as I'm a new user, sorry.

Comment: Ur welcome. OSX has very robust caching. Things like Info.plist is only gleamed once, and notification daemon will go to cache, not the app, to look for this metadata/information. So if you have saved the automator applet as untitled at first, CFBundleName string would have been made up randomly. The system doesn't keep track of changes to any file. It only updates its cache if you rename app in Finder, and re-rename it back.